# Ставить запятую или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Наткнулся:
"Впрочем, я сам её так до сих пор и не прочитал и это очень стыдно".
Смутило отсутствие запятой.
Вопрос: можно ли рассматривать "и это очень стыдно" как некую присоединительную/пояснительную (?) конструкцию или нет? (т.е. ставить запятую).
Или здесь нужно подходить к "и это стыдно" только как к части сложного предложения (т.е. ставить запятую)?
Речь в предложении про книгу, естественно.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна, если `впрочем` относится к обоим простым предложениям (которые равны между собой по важности).

Правило: если простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого предложения имеют общее вводное слово или вводное словосочетание, то запятая не ставится. Здесь слово `впрочем` вводное.

Источник (пункт 2.г): https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/733-12_znaki_prepinaniya_v_slozhnosochinennyh_predlozheniyah.html

Но если второе простое предложение является выводом из первого, то нужно ставить запятую. А это более логично, поэтому лучше поставить запятую.

Answer (score 0):

Отсутствие запятой не ошибка, но я бы её не опускал в данном тексте.
Если бы вы прямо задали вопрос о запятой, то я бы этим ответом и ограничился. Но вы еще какие-то объяснения привели, которые, на мой взгляд, только путают. Давайте сначала с ними попытаемся разобраться.

> Вопрос: можно ли рассматривать "и это очень стыдно" как некую
>   присоединительную/пояснительную (?) конструкцию или нет?

Не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотели сказать. И совсем непонятно, зачем тут что-то изобретать. Какая еще конструкция?

> > (т.е. ставить запятую).

Ну да, ставить. А причем тут "конструкция"?

> > Или здесь нужно подходить к "и это стыдно" только как к части сложного предложения (т.е. ставить запятую)?

Только так и нужно.

А вот мотивировать отсутствие запятой можно тем, что, дескать, два простых, составляющих сложносочиненное предложение, однородны и у них есть общий член - "впрочем". Других аргументов я тут не вижу.

Но вижу что однородность эта весьма услоловна, а трактовка этого "впрочем" как общего члена - спорна. То есть все - на волю автора.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна.

"Впрочем, я сам её так до сих пор и не прочитал, и это очень стыдно"

Вы сами верно ответили на свой вопрос. Это присоединительная конструкция.

Если бы было, например, так: "Я сам ее так до сих пор и не прочитал и не жалею об этом", запятая была бы не нужна. Но здесь "это", которое напрямую не является прямым продолжением "я", а образует дополнительную конструкцию, поэтому запятая нужна.